# Are the words "function", "map", and "mapping" synonymous?

Tags: definition

Is it correct to say that

"A *function* or a *map* or a *mapping* is a binary relation such that ..."

Comment: Depends on the author.

Comment: I'd think you'd write it as "function, map, or a mapping"

Comment: Yes. And also the phrases "taken as synonyms" and "taken to be synonymous" are synonymous.

Comment: Yes I wanted to make my question turn up more often in search results =D

Comment: Better to say:  "A *function* is a binary relation such that ... . *Functions* may also be called *maps* or *mappings*.

Comment: I edited the title.  Search engines are smart enough to realize that synonym and synonymous are synonymous, so you don't need to include keywords in a title.  I couldn't find any `Meta SE` discussion on this topic although there is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) saying not to include tags in the title.

Comment: @Mike: Could you give an example of an author who defines "function" and "map" differently?

Comment: @KennyLJ John Lee, "Smooth Manifolds", a function on a smooth manifold is (to him) a function $f: M \rightarrow \Bbb R^k$; a map is just in the set-theoretic sense (where it is, indeed, synonymous with function).

Comment: @Mike: Could you refer me to the book title and page number of this? It sounds like he is defining what a *function on a smooth manifold* is, which is a special type of *function*. So for example, you could likewise say that I define a *real-valued function* differently from a *map*, because a real-valued function is a map with the set of real numbers as the codomain.

Comment: @KennyLJ Yes, you're correct. I was only providing a context where the *words* weren't used for the same meaning. In a set-theoretic context I've never seen any author that uses these words differetly, in my meager experience.

Comment: Sometimes "map" or "mapping" specifically denotes a function that's continuous, smooth, etc. (depending on what category you're working in), while "function" means any function of sets. Then again, "function" also often gets employed in the former usage as well.